# "Tried to Synchronously call anonymous function from a different thread."

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation, react-native-reanimated

I have this issue whenever I toggle the drawer on my screen. I want to login and then go to Home page where there will be a drawer. But I don't know where the issue is.

PS: I have Expo managed project and I already installed react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated.

This is the code for navigating :

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Test} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Reset" component={Reset} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="StartUp" component={StartUp} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Reset" component={Reset} />
      <Stack.Screen name="DrawerComponent" component={DrawerComponent} options={{title: "drawer"}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the components in your drawer navigator?

Comment: I'm also getting this error, I believe it's when react-navigation is using the reanimated library